# Can I get my deposit from back buyers agreement for motorcycle?

Tags: refund

I put a deposit on a 2020 motorcycle at this particular dealer 20 minutes away because the next dealer is over a hour away. The  dealer said they had already had ordered the bike I wanted, and that it would be 2-3 weeks. After 2 weeks, he's saying he doesn't know when it'll be in. Other dealers have the bike I want, so don't know what's the issue. But I put a cash deposit down. I'm assuming its it's up to the dealer if he wants to refund any money at all . There's a "buyer's agreement" without my signature on it. I tend to be too fast  with these things.

Comment: #1 Do you have a receipt for the down payment?  #2 Does the buyer's agreement say that the DP is refundable?

Comment: I find it odd that next year’s model can be delivered this year.

Comment: That is normal, in the US anyway.

Comment: @Lawrence Model year N+1 vehicles typically become available some time in the (northern hemisphere) fall of year N, so a model year 2020 vehicle becoming available in September or October 2019 is not unreasonable.

Comment: @aCVn It may not be _uncommon_, but I'd still call it _unreasonable_!

Comment: Which country? Does the buyers agreement mention a time period? is there a section about canceling the deal?

Comment: If you can find the name of the brand's regional manager and give them a call yourself, they may be willing to help persuade the dealers to cooperate on an inventory deal to get the bike to you from one of the other stores.

Answer (score 0):

In the general case you have an agreement that you put down a deposit and you were promised the bike in 2-3 weeks. The dealer didn't keep their promise so at the very least you can ask for your money back. If they're unwilling to refund your deposit you could go a more litigious route.

Either way it's unreasonable to give a deposit for a delivery at an unspecified timeframe in the future.

Ask for a refund of the deposit and see what they say.

Comment: Thanks for the respones I appreciate  them. Yeah I moved too fast got a lil excited. The agreement says delivery as soon as possible. Nothing about a refund. And I do have the receipt.Thing about it is other dealers have them. They are twice as far I considered that's why I was  going here. Also the salesman gave me a tip on selling my last bike and it sold the next week.

Comment: I give it a few more days and see what their policy is

Comment: You have no idea what anyone promised without reading the agreement. It's not clear at all that the dealer didn't deliver on a promise.